# What is the use for code formatting?

Tags: discussion, support, formatting

So in the tool bar (that’s what I like to call it), the bar that appears when you edit/ask a question or answer: (sorry for my terrible handwriting)

[image]

So after thinking about it I can’t see any use for the code formatting tool so I wonder if there is. You would format sentence examples with a blockquote specific words with bold or italics.

Anyone got any opinions or ideas of what it could be used for?

Could we remove it form the toolbar?

Comment: Howdy - if the question I linked as a duplicate doesn't answer your question, please edit your question to explain why and we should be able to reopen it.

Comment: @ColleenV Edited

Comment: No, we can't change the toolbar as far as I know. That would be a feature request that should be posted on the main [Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Isofar as I know, the toolbar is consistent and standard across every Stack Exchange. Just because one exchange is unlikely to use a button doesn't mean it should be removed from that exchange.

Comment: @J.R. Actually, it's not entirely consistent. Most of the icons, including the `{}` for preformatted code are, but some sites *add* icons. For example, I know for sure that OP's screenshot is from another site since it adds the `<>` button which is for Stack Snippets.

Comment: @Laurel My screenshot is from another site